# Showing "Cannot create SSL client. SSL is not enabled in this build" when connecting to Cosmos DB (MongoDB API)

Tags: centos, nginx, mongodb, php7

I am facing the error "Cannot create SSL client. SSL is not enabled in this build" when connecting to CosmosDB using the MongoDB API.

My PHP configuration suggests SSL support is included in my MongoDB driver:

```
$ php --ri mongodb

mongodb

MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.4.4
MongoDB extension stability => stable
libbson bundled version => 1.9.4
libmongoc bundled version => 1.9.4
libmongoc SSL => enabled
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => disabled
libmongoc compression => enabled
libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
libmongoc compression zlib => enabled
```

I'm using Centos 7, Nginx web server, php-fpm 7.1 but failed to connect to Cosmos because of this SSL error.

I already tried installing:

```
- sudo pecl install openssh-devel
- sudo pecl install mongodb-1.4.4
```

The result is that `libmongoc` is enabled but still showing same error : "Cannot create SSL client. SSL is not enabled in this build."

Comment: Cosmos's MongoDB API is a separate implementation that doesn't share any code with the MongoDB server. Based on your output it looks like SSL support is enabled in your PHP driver, so perhaps the client error message is misleading. In order to test if SSL is available and working, I suggest trying to connect to a free tier [MongoDB Atlas cluster](https://mongodb.com/atlas). There's also a thread in the MongoDB PHP driver issue queue with some debugging tips that may help: [#348: Connection fail due to SSL](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/issues/348).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

already got the answer. turns out mongodb in cosmos using version 3.x that should using driver 1.4.4 and cannot using 1.5.x

once libmongoc SSL => enabled when installed openssh-devel first then install mongodb-1.4.4, the SSL connection is good and the problem is not showing again. cheers.